# NestJS and Express causing intermittent UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I cannot for the life of me cannot figure this out. It happens once every so often doesn't cause any issues with the application itself but i have no idea what is causing this. Im making simultaneous calls to the api from the browser if that has anything to do with it.

```
[Nest] 16608   - 11/7/2018, 1:23:08 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started
[Nest] 16608   - 11/7/2018, 1:23:23 PM   [LoggerMiddleware] Request /api/observation-statement/pending-count +14943ms
[Nest] 16608   - 11/7/2018, 1:23:23 PM   [LoggerMiddleware] Request /api/observation-statement/revision-count +16ms


(node:14968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:469:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at ExpressAdapter.reply (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\adapters\express-adapter.js:44:52)
at ExceptionsHandler.catch (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\exceptions\base-exception-filter.js:16:33)
at ExceptionsHandler.next (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\exceptions\exceptions-handler.js:15:20)
at C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:23:35
at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Ricardo Saracino\IdeaProjects\sor-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
(node:14968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14968) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've reduced the calls to a pretty simple function, and make sure the call is returning a unique value (i thought it might be a 304 issue)

```
@Get('revision-count')
async countRevisions(@User() user, @Param() params) {

    user.count ++;

    return {
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            rand: user.count,
        }
    };
}
```

> this was happening prior to the middleware

Comment: Is it possible that somewhere in your application you have an async function that isn't being awaited? The stack trace indicates that your code is falling into the global error handler which returns a default error message but in this case your application has already returned a response to the client so the error handler itself is failing. I had this exact same issue in my app and the underlying was a promise that wasn't being awaited

Comment: i was thinking its the Nest Framework im using or a library.. i have no idea how to track it down though

Comment: Are you able to upload a small repo that reproduces this issue?